# Laravel Code into Javascript?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using dropzone.js in my Laravel App to upload images. The Code looks like this:

```
<script>
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    paramName: 'file',
    maxFilesize: 5, // MB
    maxFiles: 20,
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
};
</script>
```

I want to make "maxFiles" more dynamic and load it with data from database. I have a table "cat" where field "count" is populated with a number. I can show the number using

```
$cat->count
```

I tried with

```
maxFiles: $cat->count - not working
maxFiles: {{ $cat->count }} - not working
```

Can someone advice me how to solve this issue?

Kind Regards,

Stefan

Update:

This Lines have been updated as they are indeed important. It looks like, that the Javascript will never be called:

```
 <form data-count= "{{ $cats->count }}" action="{{ route('upload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="fileupload" method="POST">
        @csrf
        {{ Form::hidden('cat_id', $cats->id) }}
        <div class="fallback">
          <input name="file" type="files" multiple accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg" />
        </div>
      </form>
```

The Route:

```
 Route::post('upload' , 'ProjectController@upload')->name('upload');
```

Comment: you write this code in a JavaScript file or in blade.php?

Comment: one way is to query the db using an ajax call, and update the maxfiles, you cant simply paste php code in javascript

Comment: @Dry7: the Javascript Code is in the blade.php

Comment: @Shobi: oh, I see

Comment: try to see what happens with this `{{ dd($cat->count) }}`

Comment: When you use `{{ $cat->count }}` what does generated source look like in browser?

Comment: Dear Lewis4u - thank you for your feedback. It looks like that Javascript never will be called...

Comment: Dear Lewis4u and Charlie: $cat->count is showing 5 (this is the expected result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work? It should... wonder if it's the definition of the annonimous object that mixes it up...

```
<script>
var max = {{ $cat->count }};
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    paramName: 'file',
    maxFilesize: 5, // MB
    maxFiles: max,
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
};
</script>
```

Comment: Dear Serge, thank you for your Feedback. I have found the same code on another site, so it should work - but it looks like, that my Javascript Code never will be called - I have updated the original Code...